# Why update manager is still showing a development release?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, stable-release-updates

Though Ubuntu 14.04 has been officially released, `update-manager -d` says that the distribution will be upgraded to a development version, still in testing.

Why? How long will I have to wait to have the stable in the repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `man` page of `update-manager`, the `-d` option:

```
  -d, --devel-release
              Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible
```

So you are already asking `update-manager` to try and upgrade to a development release. Remove the`-d` and it will work